# How to create some independent windows in QML

Tags: qt, window, qml

I want to create a start window like in Wolfram Mathematica, where the user can create/open file, after this window get hidden, and the program create a new window with the file editor, after closing the editor, the editor window get closed and the program show again the start window. How to make some independent windows in QML?

Comment: By using [`ApplicationWindow`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qtquick-controls2-applicationwindow.html)?

Comment: I use Window QML type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to have them static, and independent, it might be one idea to create multiple windows from C++.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    engine.load(QUrl(QUrl("./main_0.qml")));
    engine.load(QUrl(QUrl("./main_1.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty()) {
        qDebug() << "crap";
    }

    return app.exec();
}
```

Then use any kind of common data model (e.g. context properties, singletons ...) to set them visible.

Comment: It's an ideal solution.

Comment: You had simplified my main function: https://gitlab.com/lixcode/icL/commit/ae68dbbd89fc6581e63275ab5f9474cf282bac0e

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this:

Start.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.11

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Start Window")
    onClosing: {
        var component = Qt.createComponent("qrc:/Editor.qml");
        component.createObject();
    }
}
```

Editor.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.11

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Editor")
    onClosing: {
        var component = Qt.createComponent("qrc:/Start.qml");
        component.createObject();
    }
}
```

Closing one view will make the other view appear. So you probably should add another button for the case that the user wants to completely quit the application.

If you want your views to be created only once, you can ignore the close event and set the visibility instead. You can for example do something like this:

Start.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.11

Window {
    id: mainStartView
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Start Window")
    property var editorView

    Component.onCompleted: {
        editorView = editorComponent.createObject(mainStartView);
    }

    onClosing: {
        close.accepted = false
        editorView.visible = true
        mainStartView.visible = false
    }

    Component {
        id: editorComponent
        Editor {
            visible: false
        }
    }
}
```

Editor.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.11

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Editor")
    onClosing: {
        close.accepted = false
        mainStartView.visible = true
        visible = false
    }
}
```

Comment: The windows are created dinamicaly, but a think a pair of static windows will be a better choise.

Comment: If you use `component.createObject()` without specifying a parent, you never know when the gc decides to wipe your screen. Maybe this is not an issue in newer Qt-Versions but in Qt5.6 it had the tendency to make some unexpected decisions...

Comment: @L.V.A see modified answer